# Is there an editors checklist for mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

I always have trouble with editing math papers for publication.  I know there are plenty of checklists for English exposition but is there one for math specific exposition errors?

Comment: Could you possibly link to one of these English exposition checklists; it is not quite clear to me what you are looking for. There are several short books, booklets, other documents that give advice on math writing. But it seems you are after something more specific. It is however not clear to me what it is precisely. 

Comment: Something like this: http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CommonErrors.html.

Its not a book but a short list of "before you submit anything look to see if you did any of these things!"

Comment: You will definitely benefit from the book: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719550 (*Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences*, N. Higham, SIAM).

Answer (score 25):

Please have a look on these two lists ([this one](https://www.impan.pl/wydawnictwa/dla-autorow/errors.pdf) and [that one](http://www.m-fozouni.ir/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Writing-Mathematical-Papers-in-English_-A-Practical-Guide-European-Mathematical-Society-2005.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks!  I wonder if others have other versions of this.

Comment: @Daniel Parry: I am not sure what you mean by 'other versions' but there is a brief booklet (about 50 pages) by the same author published  by the EMS: Jerzy Trzeciak, Writing Mathematical Papers in English, a practical guide http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=34 

  

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as above: look at the video where Jean-Pierre Serre explains in English how to write mathematics - badly!

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xf88b5_jean-pierre-serre-writing-mathemati_tech#.UTsRq44zVHI

Often hilarious, but so true...

Answer (score 1):

See Also:

Steenrod, N.E.; Halmos, P.R.; Schiffer, M.M.; Dieudonné, Jean A.;
How to write mathematics. American Mathematical Society (1973).